# Socket.io's broadcast.emit being used incorrectly here?

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io, broadcast

This chat application I'm working on as practice (being new to Node and Socket.IO) is doing well except for the fact that I can't get the server to broadcast messages to all the clients. I've checked for inconsistent variables (and may have created some while playing around, my apologies ;P) but it's not working? I'm confused because I'm not receiving any console errors or anything like that, making this incredibly hard to debug. Could it be that I'm running into my first encounter with how callbacks can end up nesting in an unwanted manner?

Anyway, here's some code:

**App.js:**

```
// Require dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Listen for connections
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {

  console.log("Someone is connecting...");

  client.on('join', function(name) {
    client.set('nickname', name);
    console.log(name+" has connected!");
    client.broadcast.emit('connected', name + " has connected");
  });

  // Receive messages from the client and broadcast them to everyone
  client.on('messages', function(data) {

    client.get('nickname', function(err, name) {
      client.broadcast.emit("chat", name + ": " + data);
    });

  });
});

// Without this line, the CSS will not work
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Route index.html to the root path
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

// Listen for GET requests to the server
server.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chatapp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/default.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Chatapp</h1>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="online">

            </div>

            <div id="body">
                <div id="status"></div>
                <div id="chat">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="input">
                <form id="chatform">
                    <input type="text" id="message"></input>
                    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send!"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Wait until DOM is ready
            $(document).ready(function() {

                // Establish a connection to the server
                var server = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

                // On submit, send the chat form message to the server, prevent default redirect and reset the chat form
                $('#chatform').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var message = $('#message').val();
                    server.emit('messages', message);
                    $('#chatform')[0].reset();
                });

                server.on('connect', function(data) {
                    nickname = prompt('What is your nickname?');
                    $('#status').html('Connected to Chatapp as ' +nickname);
                    server.emit('join', nickname);
                });

                server.on('connected', function(data) {
                    $('<p>'+data+'</p>').appendTo('#chat');
                });

                // Listen for messages broadcasted to every client by the server - this does not work for some reason.
                server.on('chat', function(data) {
                    $(data).appendTo('#chat');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**/public/default.css:**

```
body {
  margin:  0;
  padding:  0;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #00B7FF;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:  940px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#online {
    float: left;
    width: 188px;
    height: 480px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    color: #eee;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px #fff, inset -1px -1px 0px #fff;
}

#body {
    float: left;
    width: 731px;
    height: 439px;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#status {
    color: #eee;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px #fff, inset -1px -1px 0px #fff;
}

#chat {
    background: #c4f2eb;
    height: 388px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px #fff, inset -1px -1px 0px #fff;
}

#input {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    width: 731px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

h1.title {
    text-align: center;
}

input#message {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 640px;
    height: 58px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

input#message:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #55ba57, inset -1px -1px 3px #55ba57;
}

input#send {
    float: left;
    background: #55ba57;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 81px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px #fff, inset -1px -1px 0px #fff;
}

input#send:hover {
    background: #489949;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input#send:active {
    background: #1e7520;
}
```

Comment: your code seems fine to me now that i've gone over it again, can i see your client code for handling `connected`

Comment: All of the client side code is within <script> tags in the index.html (near the bottom)

Comment: ah, sorry, not used to it being in one file

Comment: I usually keep it all in one file when it's small enough - forsive habit

Comment: could you give `io.sockets.emit` a quick try?

Comment: I gave it a try in place of `client.broadcast.emit` and I'm seeing the same lack of result. I'm intrigued - isn't `io.sockets.emit` different to `client.broadcast.emit`?

Comment: are you sure its not receiving it? have you placed a `console.log` in your client function in the js? It's just a different way of referring to all connected sockets

Comment: this is something I did a while back which uses both methods : https://github.com/f0xy/Socket-Server-IO/blob/master/server.js line 64 onward

Comment: I'm 100% sure. I have put a `console.log` in each function to test and no result. Oddly enough, I cannot `alert(data)` either. Client is sending information to the server fine, but not the other way around

Comment: `client.broadcast.emit('connected', {data : name + 'has connected!'});` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, let's break this problem up into many little sub-problems ;)

1. When you say you can't log (or alert) `data`, at which point are you trying this? (Problem from your comments)

   If this is in `server.on('connect', function(data) {...` you'll never get any data. The `connect` event is purely informational.
2. Both of these do not send the data back to the client who `connected\chat`s.

   ```
   client.broadcast.emit('connected', name + " has connected");
   client.broadcast.emit("chat", name + ": " + data);
   ```

   So if you want them printed in the same client window, you'll have to also `client.emit` directly under them, to send the message to the client window who caused the actions.

   Edit: This is from the docs: Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except for the socket that starts it.
3. Your server broadcasts `chat` events, but your client is listening for `messages` events only. (FIXED)

Let me know if you have any other issues.

- I would not call the sockets you created 'server' on the client and 'client' on the server. Makes it all a little confusing. ;)

Comment: 1. Within the callbacks that listen for and receive them on the client side. Not in `server.on('connect'...`. I just ask for a username on the join event there, and that data gets submitted to the server.

2. If `client.broadcast.emit` is used to send the message to every client, what is the purpose of sending the information a second time?

3. They both broadcasted/listened for `messages` events and I thought that was the issue prior to posting the question (hence why I said I might have created some inconsistent variables). It still doesn't work... :(

Comment: Oddly enough I changed all of the server/client variables to be `socket` and now the console logs `debug - broadcasting packet` when I type a message into the chat box. I'd say that's progress, but it does not display the message still.

Comment: OK, now you just need to re-read problem 2's explanation and things might start to work.

Comment: I did, it didn't work at first but that was because of a different datatype I forgot to remove when trying a different solution. The guides I'm following make no mention of having to `socket.broadcast.emit` as well as `socket.emit`, can you explain why this is necessary? I thought `socket.broadcast.emit` would work on it's own...?

Comment: You can read the official docs here: http://socket.io/#how-to-use There is a heading about broadcasting messages. :)

Comment: good answer it was "Broadcasts are sent from a socket object and are received by all clients in the room except for the emitting socket" that got me as I wanted to send back to the client that sent, Thanks :)